# C# No Overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, linq

this is where is my error:

```
foreach (var donneesDump in don)
{
    if (cap.Any(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDump.PMRQTOTM))
    {
        if(!cap.Any(d => d.Libelle_TOT == donneesDump.Libelle_TOT))
        {
            cnn.Resultat.Add(new Resultat
            {
                NomTable = "CapitalisationActuelle",
                Groupe_D_alerte = donneesDump.Groupe_Alerte,
                NomChamp = "PMRQTOTM",
                TOTMPMRQ = donneesDump.PMRQTOTM,
                SiModifie = "Libelle TOT",
                LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT),
                LibelléTOTApres = donneesDump.Libelle_TOT,
                Remarque = "Ajoute"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

On line `LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT)`
I have two errors, which are finally the same:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type. AND Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'.

I have tried to do a `ToString()` Method to solve the problem, like this:

```
LibelléTOTAvant = ToString(cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT)),
```

and then I have the error:

> No Overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument.

It isn't the first time I have this kind of error, but I still don't find how solve this..

Thanks in advance.
Greetings.

Edit 1:

This is where I am.

```
foreach (var donneesDUMP in don)
{
    if (cap.Any(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM))
    {
        if(!cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT == donneesDUMP.Libelle_TOT))
        {
            cnn.Resultat.Add(new Resultat
            {
                NomTable = "CapitalisationActuelle",
                Groupe_D_alerte = donneesDUMP.Groupe_Alerte,
                NomChamp = "PMRQTOTM",
                TOTMPMRQ = donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM,
                SiModifie = "Libelle TOT",
                LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Select(c => c.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault(),
                //LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
                //? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                //: " ",
                LibelléTOTApres = donneesDUMP.Libelle_TOT,
                Remarque = "Modifie"
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Both of

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Select(c => c.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault(),
```

and

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
                        ? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                        : " ",
```

works. But each time I have one problem, probably with .First() and .FirstOrDefault().
It always write the first Libelle_TOT, not the good one.

Comment: What is `LibelléTOTAvant`?

Comment: type of `Libelle_TOT`?

Comment: Just check the types and modify your code according to them.

Comment: Libelle_TOT and LibelléTOTAvant are VarChar(50) data type.

Comment: You should use something like this `LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT=="YourString")`. Also you can 'LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Select(c => c.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault() '

Comment: @Slava I have a little problem with the method "FirstOrDefault". I always return the first value, even if it's the 2nd one who should be matched. Do you know by what I have to replace FirstOrDefault() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `Libelle_TOT` is a string (from the `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'.` error message)

`cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT)` doesn't make sense in this case, as `Any` should have a `Func<T, bool>` as argument (something returning a bool) and you pass a `Func<T, string>`.

So you should do

```
cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
```

for example, or anything else needed which would return a bool.

and if `LibelléTOTAvant` is a string

```
cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
   ? <something which is a string>
   : <something else which is a string>
```

**EDIT**

for example

```
cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
   ? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
   : 'No Label'
```

or in this case, you could do

```
   cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)) ?? 'No Label'
```

Comment: I have tried your code    LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT)),   and I have the Opposite error than before, cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to string'

Comment: @Kraenys yes, so add a `.ToString()` at the end of that line (but you will have `true` or `false`, which is maybe not what you want), or use the last code in my answer.

Comment: Indeed, it isn't what I look for. I don't understand what you mean with "? <something which is a string>" and ": <something else which is a string>"

Comment: @Kraenys it's a ternary operator (if... then... else)

Comment: @Kraenys I edited the edit for a probably easier solution in this case.

Comment: I have tried to use LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
                            ? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                            : " ",

And it works, but the .First is a problem, it always returns the same value, and not the expected one. Have got any idea why?