# Method 'First' or 'FirstOrDefault' don't give the right data

Tags: c#, wpf, database, linq, visual-studio-2013

***The message in front of mine isn't correct, don't get an answer into the other post.***

This is the portion of the code in which I have a problem.

Libelle_TOT and Groupe_Alerte are VarChar(50)

```
foreach (var donneesDUMP in don)
    {
        if (cap.Any(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM))
        {
            if(!cap.Any(c => c.Libelle_TOT == donneesDUMP.Libelle_TOT))
            {
                cnn.Resultat.Add(new Resultat
                {
                    NomTable = "CapitalisationActuelle",
                    Groupe_D_alerte = donneesDUMP.Groupe_Alerte,
                    NomChamp = "PMRQTOTM",
                    TOTMPMRQ = donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM,
                    SiModifie = "Libelle TOT",
                    LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Select(c => c.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault(),
                    //LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
                    //? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                    //: " ",
                    LibelléTOTApres = donneesDUMP.Libelle_TOT,
                    Remarque = "Modifie"
                });
            }
```

Both of

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Select(c => c.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault(),
```

and

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
                    ? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                    : " ",
```

works, I haven't any building errors. But each time I have one problem, probably with .First() and .FirstOrDefault(). It always write the first Libelle_TOT, not the good one.

This is an example of what I get:
http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=14/35/6ri4.png

The LibelléTOTAvant has sometimes the same value (test5) because test5 is the first line of the table capitalisationActuelle, but it isn't the correct value. For example, for LibelléTOTApres = qfd, I should get test3 and not test5, etc.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you expect it should do? What is "the good one"? You say yourself that it "always write the first ..." - that is exactly what First/FirstOrDefault should - hence the name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# No Overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520919/c-sharp-no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-argument)

Comment: @Slava you answered an other question Slava, indeed. But now my problem is different. It works but don't give the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you probably need to select the specific row matching the PMRQTOTM of the current donneesDUMP:

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.First(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM).LibelleTOT;
```

Note that it's a WHERE condition inside the First() selecting rows matching the specified condtion, and a First to get the first (and now only) row - same as the more verbose version:

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Where(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM).First().LibelleTOT;
```

Comment: LibelléTOTAvant = cap.First(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDUMP.PMRQTOTM).LibelleTOT;
was precisely what I was looking for. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Well, this:

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Select(c => c.Libelle_TOT).FirstOrDefault(),
```

will just select the first `Libelle_TOT` of cap, since you're not giving any condition

And this:

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT))
                    ? cap.Select(x => x.Libelle_TOT).First(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                    : " ",
```

should select the first non-empty `Libelle_TOT`, although you could just replace it by:

```
LibelléTOTAvant = cap.FirstOrDefault(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Libelle_TOT));
```

As it would give you null if there is no empty libelle.

Are you just trying to select the first non empty libelle?

Comment: I'm not trying to get the first non empty libelle.
this is one of the database: capitalisationActuelle
[link](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=14/35/qcxl.png)

The other one is the same, with different values. I check if a "PMRQTOTM" of one table exist in the other one, and if it exists, I check if the "libelleTOT" is the same or not. If it's a different one, I insert it into "LibelléTOTAvant"

Comment: But the problem is, when every conditions are validated (same "PMRQTOTM", different "libelleTOT", it doesn't insert the corresponding "libelleTOT" into "LibelléTOTAvant" but the first "libelleTOT" of the table.

Comment: Whoops, already answered, I'm too late there but yeah, you were just not querying the right thing indeed